# How to ensure custom branch links do not redirect to app.link url

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

How can I prevent users from being redirected to the app.link domain URL and ensure that my custom link domain URLs from Branch, such as subdomain.myapp.app, are displayed when navigating to the deepview page?

I tried the redirect allowlist feature hoping it would prevent the user from seeing the app.link url in the browser but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. When custom link domain is added to the Branch app, we use that domain to create the links. However, all the users that click on that link are first redirected to the default branch link domain which is the app.link domain.